# OO Design query adapter

Tags: design-patterns, adapter, ooad

I have one query regarding Adapter pattern, how to implement in this scenario.
I have one interface which return type is single object.

```
public interface MyInt {
MyObj read();
}
```

However, my adaptee implementation class say, MyAdaptee has method which return list of MyObj object.

```
public class MyAdaptee {
public MyObj[] readTheInput() {
// implementation here
}
```

Now, how can i write adapter here on top of MyAdaptee?
since I can't change the interface, how can i send multiple object of MyObj to client which expect single object?

PS: MyObj is also interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement Adapter using its semantics, and hence, may have to modify the Adaptee implementation such that it returns array items one by one by keeping track of what it has returned earlier.

Below is indicative implementation, I have not compiled or tested it, so take it for logic it represents.

```
public class MyAdaptee implements MyInt {
     private MyObj[] buffer = new MyObj[0];
     private indexOfLastBufferedItemReturned = 0;

  @Override
  public MyObj read() {
     if (indexOfLastBufferedItemReturned >= buffer.length) {
        buffer = readTheInput(); //use existing implementation here
        indexOfLastBufferedItemReturned = 0;
     }
     return buffer[indexOfLastBufferedItemReturned++];   
  }

  public MyObj[] readTheInput() {    
     // implementation here   
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks but how will you return multiple object to client? For instance, reaTheInput() return three MyObj, now once you return first index to adapter and adapter send to client, afterwards, how will you again send to adapter (and to client)? I am sorry, if i am missing any thing?

Comment: Client will call the method multiple times as client knows only about MyInt which supports reading one MyObj at a time

Comment: Not unless it still has elements to return from previous call of readInput, only if buffer is empty it should issue call to readInput to get more MyObjs

Comment: sorry, i delete my comment. Thanks a lot for your help. \